# Airflow Task Skip and passing taskinstance between tasks

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, skip

I made a Airflow DAG.

This DAG's scenario is below.

- Assume that Query Job 1, Query Job 2, and Query Job 3 exist that must be driven sequentially.
- In the event of a Query Task error. After SKIP all the tasks, send an error email(not System Email).
- In case of an error, do not re-execute the task.

So. I tried like this.

```
QUERY_LIST = [
    SELECT_T_CLA_EDA_QUERY, 
    CREATE_NT_CLA_EDA_QUERY, 
    SELECT_NT_CLA_EDA_QUERY
]
default_args = {
    'owner': 'ParkHG',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    "wait_for_downstream": True,
    'retries': 0
}

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID, 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval='@once' 
) as dag:
    global glb_ti

    success_finish = DummyOperator(task_id = 'success_finish', dag = dag)

    def make_email_html_form(**kwargs):
        global glb_ti
        ti = glb_ti
        
        url = ti.log_url
        #tag1 = '--'
        tag2 = ti.current_state()
        tag3 = ti.dag_id
        tag4 = ti.duration
        #tag5 = '--'
        tag6 = ti.job_id
        tag7 = ti.get_previous_start_date()
        tag8 = ti.task_id
        tag9 = ti.operator
        
        html = F"""some html code used taskinstance object"""
        
        return html

    def checkpoint_status(index, **kwargs):
        execution_date = kwargs['execution_date']

        operator_instance = kwargs['dag'].get_task("bigquery_task_"+str(index))
        global glb_ti
        glb_ti = TaskInstance(operator_instance, execution_date)
        status = glb_ti.current_state()

        if status != 'success':
            task_id = 'make_email_html'
        else:
            if index < (len(QUERY_LIST)-1):
                task_id = "bigquery_task_"+str(index+1) 
            else:
                task_id = 'success_finish'

        return task_id
    
    airflow_email_operator = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email',
        to=['gusrbs82@cloocus.com'],
        subject='Airflow Alert',
        html_content="{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='make_email_html')}}",
        dag=dag
    )

    make_email_html = PythonOperator(
        task_id='make_email_html',
        python_callable=make_email_html_form,
        #op_kwargs = {'glbti' : glb_ti},
        trigger_rule='one_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )

    for i in range(0,len(QUERY_LIST)):

        check_situation = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id='check_situation_'+str(i),
            python_callable=checkpoint_status,
            op_kwargs = {'index' : i},
            #trigger_rule='all_done',
            dag=dag,
        )

        task = bigquery.BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id="bigquery_task_"+str(i),
            configuration={
                "query": {
                    "query": QUERY_LIST[i],
                    "useLegacySql": False
                }
            },
            location=location,
            dag = dag
        )
        
        if i == 0:
            task >> check_situation >> make_email_html
        else:
            this_run >> task >> check_situation >> make_email_html
        
        
        if i < (len(QUERY_LIST)-1):
            this_run = check_situation
        else:
            check_situation >> success_finish
        
        make_email_html >> airflow_email_operator
```

This code shows as shown in the figure below.
However, if an error occurs in 'big query_task_1', the tasks after that cannot be skipped.
and.. i can receive taskinstance object from check_situation task.
[image]

What's the problem?

- Is it because we designated the task as global?
- Is it because the trigger_rule of branch pythonoperation is set incorrectly?
- or... others...?

when i use check_situation's trigger_rule : 'all_done'
result is below picture.
[image]

Comment: why did you comment  `#trigger_rule='all_done'` in `check_situation` ? According to your description you need `trigger_rule='all_done'`

Comment: hi Elad. I tried this trigger_rule. but it same. doesn't work. pls check my picture.

Comment: Please check the error notifications in Airflow. https://www.astronomer.io/guides/error-notifications-in-airflow

it looks to me that what you are trying to do is the general notification on any failures.

Comment: HI. Emma. i solved this problem using you gave the link. It was a really useful post. Thank you very much.